# Why I add the "cppInclude" parser then the whole g4 doesn't work

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, dsl

g4:

```
grammar KBDP;

@header {package kbdp.translator.antlr;}

COMMENT:   '/*' .*? '*/'    -> skip ; LINE_COMMENT: '//' ~[\r\n]* '\r'? '\n' -> skip;


KS:'[' ('KS_'|'KA_') MIX+ ']';

STRING : '"' ~[\r\n"]+ '"';

fragment NUM:[0-9]+; VARNAME:[_a-zA-Z-0-9]+;

INCLUDE :'#include' ;

MIX      : CHINESE | VARNAME ;

CHINESE  : ('\u4E00'..'\u9FA5')+ ; ARG     : VARNAME|STRING ;

DB       : '[' '数据库' ']'; SQL      : '[' 'SQL' NUM ']'; SQLRESULT: '[''SQL' NUM '有数据'']'; SQLREADLINE:'[' '列' NUM ']'; RESULTWIRTELINE:'[' '结果集' NUM ']'; RETURNMULTI:'[' '返回值' NUM '有数据' ']'; RETURNSINGLE:'[' '返回值' NUM ']'; PRINT:'[' '打印' ']';    WS: [\r\n \t] -> skip;

prog: kinglangStat+     |     cppStat+;

block:'{' prog* '}';
       kinglangStat:kinglangServiceDeclaration |
             kinglangDBOpen |
             kinglangSQL |
             kinglangSQLResult |
             kinglangSQLReadLine |
             kinglangResultDeclare |
             kinglangResultWriteLine |
             kinglangFunctionCall |
             kinglangFunctionReturnSingle |
             kinglangFunctionReturnMulti |
             kinglangPrintStatus;

kinglangServiceDeclaration: KS  '(' VARNAME? (',' VARNAME)* ')' '{' prog* '}';   kinglangDBOpen:(VARNAME '=')?  DB  '('  (VARNAME|STRING)  ')' ';'; 

kinglangSQL:(VARNAME '=')? SQL '(' STRING? ')'  ';' ;

kinglangSQLResult:SQLRESULT block;   kinglangSQLReadLine:SQLREADLINE '(' VARNAME ')' ';';   kinglangResultDeclare:RESULTWIRTELINE ';';

kinglangResultWriteLine:RESULTWIRTELINE '(' kinglangArg? (',' kinglangArg)* ')' ';';  kinglangArg : VARNAME|STRING ;

kinglangFunctionCall:KS '(' (VARNAME|STRING)? (',' (VARNAME|STRING))* ')' ';';


kinglangFunctionReturnSingle:RETURNSINGLE '(' VARNAME? (',' VARNAME)* ')' ';';

kinglangFunctionReturnMulti:RETURNMULTI block;

kinglangPrintStatus:PRINT '(' VARNAME|STRING ')' ';';

cppStat:  block          |
          cppBreakStat   |
          cppContinueStat|
          cppReturnStat  |
          cppSingleStat  |
          cppIfStat      |
          cppWhileStat   |
          cppGotoStat    |
          cppLabelStat   |
          cppForStat     |
          cppInclude;




cppIfStat: cppIfStatPart cppElseifPart* cppElsePart?;   

cppIfStatPart:'if' '(' expression ')' (cppSingleStat|block)?;

cppElseifPart:'else if' '(' expression ')' (cppSingleStat|block)? ;

cppElsePart:'else' (cppSingleStat|block)?;

cppWhileStat:'while' '(' expression ')' block;

cppForStat:'for' '(' cppForCondition1?';' cppForCondition2?';'cppForCondition3?')' block; cppForCondition1:expression; cppForCondition2:expression; cppForCondition3:expression;

cppBreakStat:'break' ';';

cppContinueStat:'continue' ';';

cppGotoStat:'goto' expression ';' ;

cppLabelStat:VARNAME ':' ;

cppReturnStat: 'return' VARNAME? ';';

cppSingleStat: expression ';';  

cppInclude: INCLUDE ('<'|'"') VARNAME '.' VARNAME ('>'|'"') ';';

expression:  VARNAME |
             STRING |
             '!' expression |
             expression '=' expression |
             expression ('<'|'>') expression |
             expression  expression |
             expression ('+'|'-'|'*'|'/'|'%') expression |
             expression ('=='|'!=') expression |
             expression ('>='|'<=') expression |
             expression ('&&'|'||') expression |
             expression ('++'|'--') |
             ('++'|'--') expression |   
             '(' expression ')'|
             '\'' expression '\'' |
             expression ',' expression |
             expression expression |           //var decl
             expression '<' expression '>' expression |  //class template
             expression '[' expression ']' |         //array
             expression '.' expression |            //class obj
             expression '(' expression ')';         //func call
```

text:

```
[KS_MyTest](name,code)
{
    char szCredit[1024];
    memset(szCredit,0,sizeof(szCredit));

    [数据库]("DB");
    [SQL1]("select * from myTable where name='@name' and code='@code'");

    [SQL1有数据]
    {
        [列0](szCredit);
    }
    [结果集1];
    [结果集1]("ERROE_SUCCESS",0,0);

    [结果集2];
    [结果集2](szCredit);
}
```

Before add the "cppInclude" parser,everything goes well.
But when I　write the text:

```
#include <iostream.h>
[KS_MyTest](name,code)
{
}
```

the analyzer doesn't work well.
It notice me:

```
line 20:0 extraneous input '[KS_MyTest]' expecting {<EOF>, '{', '(', 'if', 'while', 'for', 'break', 'continue', 'goto', 'return', '!', '++', '--', ''', STRING, VARNAME, '#include'}
```

How could I fix the bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This production:

```
  prog: kinglangStat+     |     cppStat+;
```

says that a `prog` is either a sequence of `kinglangStat` or a sequence of `cppStat`.

Your example is a `cppStat` **followed by** a `kinglangStat` (I think).  That isn't a `prog`.

---

> How could I fix the bug?

Try this:

```
  prog: ( kinglangStat | cppStat )+;
```

or

```
  prog: stat+;
  stat: kinglangStat | cppStat;
```

(I am not a Antlr expert.  I'm just reading the grammar ... as a grammar.)

Comment: "cppInclude" belongs to  "cppStat","cppStat" belongs to "prog".What does "That isn't a prog" mean exactlly?

Comment: A mixture of `cppStat` and `kinglangStat` is not acceptable to the `prog` production / grammar rule.